# modifying mergesort to count inversions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mergesort

My question is there any better way of optimizing the code below? `inversions` is reset and incremented each time an array is merged and on the final merge of 2 sorted arrays (left & right half) we get the final value of `inversions`. Is there any better/cleaner ways of doing things without a global variable? Thanks!

```
var inversions = 0;
  function mergeSortedArray(a, b){
    var merged = [], 
        aElm = a[0],
        bElm = b[0],
        i = 1,
        j = 1,
        inversions = 0;
    while(aElm || bElm){
     if((aElm && !bElm) || aElm < bElm){
       merged.push(aElm);
       aElm = a[i++];
     }   
     else {
       merged.push(bElm);
       bElm = b[j++];
       inversions++;
     }
    }
    return merged;
  }

  function mergeSort(items){


      if (items.length < 2) {
          return items;
      }

      var middle = Math.floor(items.length / 2),
          left    = items.slice(0, middle),
          right   = items.slice(middle);

      return mergeSortedArray(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
  }
```

Comment: What do you need `inversions` for? What does it *mean*? I don't understand what it is supposed to do, apparently it's not required for the mergesort algorithm.

Comment: @Bergi An inversion is when `x > y` but `x` appears before `y` in the array.  This is the standard efficient algorithm to count the number of inversions in an array.

Comment: Ah, a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics) could have been helpful :-)

Comment: why not simple pass around a variable and also merge them, that is add them together in the backtracking step? :)

Answer (score 0):

Optimization tends to be ugly. :-)

The main performance problem that I see is that there is a lot of creating data that gets discarded as garbage.  To solve that what you can do is have an input array and an output array.  You pass into your merge function the two arrays, and the indices of where the two chunks are to merge.  Return the number of inversions.  At each level of the merge sort, the roles of input and output arrays swap.

The code will be finicky, tricky, and hard to read.  But should perform better.

As for the global, the "theoretically right" way to handle that in your code is to return a data structure with both the array and the count.  However the next best (and in my view preferred) way is to put a block around the functions that communicate through the global.  Initialize it in `mergeSort`, use it in `mergeSortedArray` and rename that routine to `_mergeSortedArray` to indicate that it is private and should not be called.  This will maintain readability, while guaranteeing correct use of the now better localized global.